# How to easily dispose forms

Tags: c#, winforms, idisposable

I'm wondering if there is someway I can automatically dispose winforms. My project is massive, with about 6 forms. I've had all sorts of errors, and they all lead to me not disposing GDI+ objects. I've added a `Dispose()` line to all my formclosing events. If there is no way to automatically dispose forms, is there any other way to stop these errors.

All the errors I've had so far are

- Parameter not valid
- Stack overflow
- Unable to create window handle

There are probably more that I don't remember, please end this month long nightmare.

**EDIT**

The latest error appears in a child form of Form1 in the child's designer. On the first line, it throws

> Error creating window handle

The stack trace is just

```
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Create(Parameters tp)
```

Comment: this may help somehow http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/12/450835.aspx

Comment: put it in `using` block?

Comment: are you creating your own GDI+ objects? in this case you need to dispose them explicitly yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally closing a form by clicking the `X` button should dispose the form object along with all it's child object since form is the parent container and so when it's dispose is called it will in turn call all it's child dispose.

But depends on what you are doing exactly in your form closing event. I have seen many people do `this.hide()` on `FormClosing` event. That means, you are not actually closing/disposing the forms.

Comment: I'm not hiding them, the only thing there is Dispose().

Comment: Then it should be fine. If the error/exception still happens post the stack trace.